# PHP array(file_get_contents(...))

Tags: php

Есть файл, в котором хранятся заблокированные IP-адреса. Он выглядит примерно так:

> `'1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8'`

Во время авторизации, PHP читает этот файл, но не может создать массив из этих IP-адресов:

> `<?php
>   $array = array (file_get_contents('ban_ips.txt'));
>   foreach ($array as $ip) {
>   ...
>   }
>   ?>`

Как сделать так, чтобы массив PHP в итоге выглядел не так:

> `$array = array ("'1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8'");`

А вот так:

> `$array = array ('1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eval конечно плохо, но думаю можно так

```
eval('$array = array ('.file_get_contents('ban_ips.txt').');');
```

или так

```
  <?php
  $array = explode(',', file_get_contents('ban_ips.txt'));

  foreach ($array as $ip) {
        $ip = trim($ip, " '");
  ...
  }
  ?>
```

3 вариант. Вместо trim используем регулярное выражение

```
<?php
  $array = explode(',', file_get_contents('ban_ips.txt'));

  foreach ($array as $ip) {
    $ip = preg_replace("/[^\d\.]/", "", $ip);
    echo $ip."<br>\n";
  }
  ?>
```

trim почем-то последную кавычку не убирает :(

Comment: Выбираю первый вариант, потому что второй не работает. Функция просто извлекает запятые для переменной.

Comment: И кстати, там, в первом варианте, вместо знаков "+" должны быть "." точки))

Comment: Попуститесь. Eval -- это грех :)

Comment: @ Lesperanza, спасибо! Добавил 3й вариант с регулярным выражением.

Comment: А почему второй-то не работает - вроде, самый вменяемый

Comment: @splash58, у меня работает. Только не пойму почему последний ip выходит с кавычкой.

Comment: Это просто загадка :) https://eval.in/409720

Comment: Ну даёте :) `$ip` в контексте `foreach` -- ЗНАЧЕНИЕ. А вы его изменять пытаетесь :) Чтобы ваш вариант заработал, надо перед `$` поставить `&`, тем самым объявив, что используем ссылку, а не значение.

Comment: С последней кавычкой разобрался. У меня в файле перенос строки стоял в виде 0D0A, а при тестирование я в границы только " '\t\n" включал. Надо " '\"\t\n\r" на все случаи жизни ставить ;)

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если стандартной функции [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php) вместо исходной строки передан массив, замена будет произведена во всех значениях массива. Более подробно можно почитать по вышеприведённой ссылке. Таким образом, ваш код может выглядеть так:

```
$ipList = str_replace("'", "", 
              // Здесь я сделал роковое допущение, что массив, способом автора,
              // успешно инициируется и надо только обрезать кавычки
              // А зря :)
              array(file_get_contents('ban_ips.txt'))
          );
foreach ($ipList as $ip) {
    echo $ip . "\n";
}
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНО:** Вопрос немного прояснился, дополню. Старое оставлю ради неочевидной информации о функции str_replace. Итак, стало быть не работал и конструктор массива. На мой взгляд вот подходящее вам решение:

```
$rawData = file_get_contents('ban_ips.txt');

$ipList = array_map(
            function($x) { // Каждому элементу отрезаем пробелы и кавычки
                return trim($x, "' ");
            },
            explode(",", $rawData)
        );

foreach ($ipList as $ip) {
    echo $ip . "\n";
}
```

P.S. Да, избегайте называть переменные служебными именами.